# Translating "wise" (not referring to a person, e.g. "wise decision")

Tags: traducción, adjetivos, vocabulario

As I understand it, `wise` is normally translated as `sabio` when referring to a person. What about when not referring to a person? For example:

> I don't think that would be a very wise decision.
>
> It would be wise to call ahead before you go.
>
> That was a very wise way of handling that situation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use "inteligente".

- No creo que esa sea una decisión muy inteligente.
- Sería inteligente llamar antes de ir.
- Fue una manera muy inteligente de gestionar la situación.

Metaphorically, you can also use "sabio" applied to non humans, such as:

- No creo que esa sea una decisión muy sabia.

Answer (score 5):

Another options is to use "sensato" (or sensata depending on the situation)

- No creo que esa sea una decisión muy sensata.
- Sería sensato llamar antes de ir.
- Esa fue una manera muy sensata de manejar esa situación.